# How to replace all smileys inside a string using a single javascript replace method?

Tags: javascript, regex

**I need a function that will Find smileys in text and replaces them
with a replacer.**

```
function myFunc(text, replacer) {
  return text.replace(/:(|:)|<3|:'(/g, replacer);
}

myFunc("Hi, :) I'm Sad :( :'( I can't but love <3 you", "*"));

//Output I want: Hi, * I'm Sad * * I can't but love * you
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(` and `)` have to be escaped in regular expressions with `\`

```js
function myFunc(text, replacer) {
  return text.replace(/:\(|:\)|<3|:'\(/g, replacer);
}

const result = myFunc("Hi, :) I'm Sad :( :'( I can't but love <3 you", "*");
console.log(result)
```